# Appcode can't get scanf right

Tags: c, jetbrains-ide, appcode

I'm really new to AppCode, I've started taking C classes and wanted to use our school license for AppCode.

Most of the others are using CodeLite and make gcc projects, when they build and run it they get a terminal window, is this possible for AppCode?

Also it requires me to input my scanf values first before any other code will be executed (see example below). This way if I have multiple scanf's it requires me to input them all at once which gets really hard to memorize if you have 10's of them.

I've searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find the answers I'm looking for, thanks a lot!

EDIT: Better example

```
puts("Give a value");
int value;
scanf("%d", &value);
```

Requires the scanf input before it prints out "Give a value", while in CodeLite it prints out "Give a value" first and afterwards it awaits the scanf input.

Comment: _For example I had an if statement which included a scanf function in the conditional brackets, yet without even knowing if the "if" statement is true it required me to input the scanf value first._ Well yes, that's because the `scanf` result is part of the conditional, and as such it *has* to be evaluated before the `if` statement can complete. If you want the `scanf` run only under certain conditions, put it in the body of the `if`-`else` statement, not in the conditional.

Comment: Even if I put in the following:
puts("Give a value");
    int value;
    scanf("%d", &value);
it asks the scanf value even before putting out "Give a value", so if I have multiple scanf's in my code it needs them all in the beginning. While in CodeLite it first puts out the put and then waits for the scanf input

Comment: **one** question at a time, please...

Comment: Maybe you need to flush the output.  `puts("Give a value"); fflush(stdout);`